# Error while trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10: "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

Tags: upgrade, 18.10

On a Lenovo laptop, I want to upgrade from **Ubuntu 18.04** to **Ubuntu 18.10 (budgie)**.

When I select upgrade on the update manager, the dialog box disappears and nothing happens. The upgrade doesn't start.

*Note- I went through the same procedure this morning on my other laptop and Ubuntu successfully upgraded.*

`do-release-upgrade` fails to upgrade and throws this error:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

What can I do to upgrade the system successfully?

Comment: Reboot your system. Open a Terminal. Try the command `do-release-upgrade`. If it fails, edit your question to include the complete terminal output.

Comment: terminal reply : "please install all available updates version before upgrading"

Comment: I found the solution after typing in the terminal "sudo apt-get update  " and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" and then launch the update manager and the upgrade started.

Comment: Note that if you have held any packages via `apt-mark hold` you'll have to unhold or remove them to avoid this error.

Answer (score 115):

**Enable upgrading from LTS to non-LTS versions (20.04 to 20.10, 18.04 to 18.10)**

On 20.04, they've added a clearer message to the failing `sudo do-release-upgrade`:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Previously, e.g. from 18.04 to 18.10, it was sometimes just giving a unclear error message as reported by the OP:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading
```

The solution to both of those is to go into:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

or access it through the Windows key dash where it is named:

> Software & Updates

Then:

- "Updates" tab
- "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown
- "For any new version"

[image]

Then as usual:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

As of 22.04, to make some of the above work, you might also need to fight ZFS out of space stuff that Ubuntu simply refuses to fix, it is so tiring: [Out of space on boot zpool and cant run updates anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293685/out-of-space-on-boot-zpool-and-cant-run-updates-anymore/1374204#1374204)

```
zfs list -t snapshot -r  | grep auto | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs -n 1 sudo zfs destroy
```

Without the `For any new version` setting, it failed to find the new version with:

```
No new release found.
```

For some reason, `apt-get` missed one of the upgrades and I got:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."
```

only `apt` worked.

**19.10 to 20.04: manually install any packages that didn't automatically upgrade**

I [came across this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-18-10-please-install-all-av/1100915?noredirect=1#comment2083538_1100915) when trying to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 and it has the same `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading` error message, so I'll also give the solution here for Googlers.

When I tried the usual:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

`sudo apt upgrade` told me:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libomp-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

and then `do-release-upgrade` gave the `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.` error.

The solution was to manually install `libomp-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libomp-dev
```

This gave me some conflict resolution options, I picked one of them, and then `do-release-upgrade` worked!

`sudo apt upgrade libomp-dev` did not work, only `apt install` did, `upgrade` failed with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libomp-dev : Depends: libomp-9-dev (>= 9~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

**`do-release-upgrade -d` enables development versions, which is not what you generally want**

I advise against `do-release-upgrade -d` unless you really know what you are doing as that upgrades to unstable development versions, which is not something that most users want.

**The upgrade only becomes available a few days/weeks after the ISO is released**

Also note that the upgrade is not released at the exact same time as the 18.10 disk comes out, it seems that you have to wait a few days until 18.10.1 is released before upgrading.

If you try `sudo do-release-upgrade` before that, you still get:

```
No new release found.
```

The ".0" ISO is also generally more buggy. E.g. when I tried the 21.04 ISO the UI was randomly crashing likely due to Wayland: [Ubuntu UI screen image freezes randomly during usage after fresh 21.04 install, suspecting Wayland or Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344736/ubuntu-ui-screen-image-freezes-randomly-during-usage-after-fresh-21-04-install) so it's generally better to just wait for the .1 to come out unless you want to help debug it.

Comment: +1 The note at the end about using `apt` instead of `apt-get` was what I needed.

Comment: Interesting, I found myself with the opposite problem, `apt` gave me the all-clear but `apt-get` showed a held back package.

Comment: Same issue here. The solution was to run `update` and `upgrade` both first with `apt` and then with `apt-get`.

Comment: ADDING THIS HELPED:
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: `sudo apt update` indicated one upgradeable package and advised `apt list --upgradable` to see it. The package in question was `virtualenvwrapper`. I then used `sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper` to do the upgrade. That solved this problem for me.

Comment: @akaihola after reading your comment I noticed that I had a similar problem upgrading to 20.04, and then solved it with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04. How did you find out that problem was with `libomp-dev`?

Comment: @BurningPapaya `sudo apt upgrade` told me as mentioned in answer :-)

Comment: After the `but it is not going to be installed` you just brushed it off and went to the next topic. I don't have broken packages and the package that's not going to be installed can't be installed because it insist on [removing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703749) [important](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350500) other packages

Answer (score 34):

I've came across the same issue when upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04. In my case the reason was that I had some packages marked as `kept back`. In this case they were related to MSSQL.

```
szymon@szymon-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1 unixodbc
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
```

I simply removed them along with their dependencies:

```
szymon@szymon-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt remove unixodbc libodbc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
freetds-bin libodbc1 msodbcsql17 mssql-tools unixodbc
```

Then the following sequence of commands led me to the successful upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

**EDIT:** Later I found [this detailed Michael's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/602) to similar question which might help achieve the same goal.

Comment: ah yeah this worked. turns out upgrades don't work until after you upgrade all packages on your pc. i guess it's a precaution to prevent issues with upgrades which makes sense - for me removing wine/upgrading it solved it

Comment: This worked like a charm!

Comment: You, sir, are a hero.

Comment: The same solution works for 21.x to 22 LTS upgrade also ! Lovely !

Comment: None of this works. Is there a FORCE upgrade or FORCE RESET that isn't like re-installed from a USB?

Comment: Ubuntu uses phased updates, which is why some updates get held back. See this for more details: https://askubuntu.com/q/1431940/2355 (The confusing wording "held back" is due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1988819))

Answer (score 20):

Install all updates and then perform the system upgrade via Terminal, that should work:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Note that `-d` upgrades to the development version, and is likely a bad idea for most users, have a look at this option instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/upgrade-form-18-04-to-18-10-issue/1100915#1100915

Comment: It is also necessary to call `apt dist-upgrade` before doing `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Even doing dist-upgrade, it still gives me the error `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`

Answer (score 6):

I had the "kept back" issue with some Wine package, but didn't need them, so just did `apt-get remove (packages)` followed by `apt-get autoremove`, and it solved the problem.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time researching this error on the internet

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

By disabling thrid-party list which solve my issue
https://tecadmin.net/resolved-please-install-all-available-updates-for-your-release-before-upgrading/

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
for i in *.list; do mv ${i} ${i}.disabled; done 
apt clean
apt autoclean 
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

Also manually check if when you use `sudo apt update`, it shows `All packages are up to date`.

Because, even if you use `sudo apt upgrade`, the system may not upgrade everything.

in my particular case, the wine wasn't upgrading at all, and because of that i couldn't successfully `sudo do-release-upgrade`. So, i removed the wine and then `sudo apt autoremove`.

After that, i could easily update my release version.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue on my Lenovo ThinkPad X240.
After 
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` 
in the Terminal, the graphical update-manager (Software Updater) worked properly...

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my 1 cent answer to the discussion: in my case there was a single `kept-back` package (`webp`) that was not "visible" asking to `apt`. I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade/dist-upgrade` and everything was fine & up-to-date. Also `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get full-upgrade/dist-upgrade` showed nothing unusual.

Then I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` and finally it spotted the culprit:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
 webp
```

And now I can upgrade!

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
You have not rebooted after updating a package which requires a reboot. Please reboot before upgrading.
```

After rebooting obviously...

Comment: What do you mean *now*? What did you do?

Comment: I don't remember if `sudo apt-get upgrade` proposed to upgrade `webp` (probably yes, so I just pressed `Y`) or I had to `sudo apt remove webp ; sudo apt install webp`, but after having the last packet up to date, I was able to upgrade to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after running `apt-get dist-upgrade` I was able to continue to `do-release-upgrade`

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade 
do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

> **CLOSE VOTERS**: Ubuntu 18.04 is the last version of Ubuntu to have a supported 32-bit upgrade path.  The upgrade path for later versions was disabled.  This is NOT "not an answer" or similar, and is an actively confirmed situation of disabled upgrade paths.  32-bit (i386) Ubuntu is no longer supported past 18.04 for upgrading to.  -- [Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward), Ubuntu Core Dev and Moderator of Ask Ubuntu

What version of the OS do you have (32/64 bit)?
The output of the terminal on my Lubuntu machine after a use of `sudo do-release-upgrade` is:

```
apt architecture is i386 

Upgrades from 18.04 on the i386 architecture are not supported at 
this time.
```

(The command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` is for upgrading to the latest development release! And it is possible from the latest release only.)

---