# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 because of "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading" error

Tags: 18.04, updates, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my version of Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I've run all the steps from updating and upgrading both apt and apt-get, changing the settings in update manager and all of the [steps described in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-18-10-please-install-all-av). Yet I keep getting the error:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Is there something special about trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 that's causing this error? Do I maybe need to update to 19.04 first?

EDIT: I just noticed something that might be important. When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following notice at the end of the output:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  colord gimagereader python-sane sane simple-scan
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Might that be causing the issue?

Comment: The update from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS won't happen until 20.04.1 is released. In the mean time, do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Will this get me to 19.04, (after running do-release-upgrade)?

Comment: I don't think so. Just wait until 20.04.1 is released.

Comment: To deal with packages being kept back try `sudo apt install -f` to fix errors.

Comment: @karel unfortunately not, when I try do-release-upgrade, I get the following error:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Comment: The issue regarding kept back packages is one I recently ran into myself and reported in the Ubuntu bug tracker at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1874927. It'd be helpful if you were to report a bug about ubuntu-release-upgrader using 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader' so that I can have a look at your log files and try and sort out why those packages are kept back. Thanks!

Comment: You can see the list of packages that can still be upgraded by `sudo apt list --upgradable` Then if the list looks good, upgrade by `sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I was also experiencing the same issue. However, when I ran the usual upgrade commands (`sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt full-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`), they were all reporting that there are no packages to upgrade and **no held packages**:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

In the end, I copied the file `/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade` to my home and modified it as follows:

```
for pkg in upgradable:
    if 'Phased-Update-Percentage' in pkg.candidate.record:
        # P-U-P does not exist if it is fully phased
        continue
    else:
        install_count += 1
        print(pkg)   # <--- ADD THIS LINE
        # one upgradeable package is enough to stop the dist-upgrade
        # break      # <--- COMMENT THIS LINE OUT to get all packages
```

This change will print the names of all packages that need to be upgraded.

When I ran `sudo ~/do-release-upgrade`, a package from an external repository was printed that had an update available, but the newer version depended on a library that was not available, which caused the package to not upgrade.

Still not sure why it wasn't reported as `not upgraded` by `apt upgrade`.

Edit: The following code snippet can be run in the Python console to list all upgradeable packages - thanks @jferard!

```py
import apt

cache = apt.Cache()
cache.open()
print([pkg for pkg in cache if pkg.is_upgradable])
```

Comment: Great, this looks like the best answer to me, as the other answer just relate to the specific environment where some users removed their stale packages. Kudos

Comment: This did it for me, had to remove wine packages, cheers!

Comment: This got it working for me, this should be accepted answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Worked for me. You can also type in a Python3 REPL : `
>>> import apt  <return>
>>> cache = apt.Cache() <return>
>>> cache.open() <return>
>>> [pkg for pkg in cache if pkg.is_upgradable]
`
to list the packages that need an upgrade.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked, I had non-upgradable 'i3status' package

Comment: This did for me. I removed nvidia drivers 390 - they were not upgradable - I thing i will change to nuuveau drivers (open soruce).

Answer (score 24):

sequence from 18.04 to 20.04

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

Follow onscreen instruction.
Good luck!

Comment: Still unable to install updated version

Comment: This didn't work for me either.

Comment: This didn't work for me as it relates to a specific package that is not being upgraded. See my answer below for a generic solution.

Comment: I came here via https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-on-wsl-2-is-generally-available. The "Good luck!" is so Linux-indicative. Thanks, the list works (minus the -f ... on my side)

Comment: I think it was the `sudo apt dist-upgrade` part that resolved it for me, what does that actually do that `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt autoremove` does not cover?

Comment: To me sudo `apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt autoremove`, followed by reboot fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is your repo is not updated, so you need to remove these five repos: `colord gimagereader python-sane sane simple-scan`

Do `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:<ppa to remove>` or edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to remove all of these repos.

Then you can run `update-manager`

Answer (score 6):

just removed wine through `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove winehq-stable` and it worked for me after reusing `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 5):

First in your terminal:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then you will get

```
The following packages have been kept back:

  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

All you have to do is to use

> sudo apt install **< Packages Names >**

The result will be like:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
```

Finally, go with:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: mine specifically `sudo apt install libc++1 libodbc1`

Answer (score 2):

Real example with solution (sorry for russian output examples, will translate it as soon as I can):

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
...
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

$ sudo apt install
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 2 пакетов не обновлено. 
// ... 2 packages are not updated

$ apt list --upgradable
Вывод списка… Готово # list output... Done
wine-stable-amd64/bionic 6.0.0~bionic-1 amd64 [может быть обновлён с: 4.0.1~bionic]
wine-stable-i386/bionic 6.0.0~bionic-1 i386 [может быть обновлён с: 4.0.1~bionic]
```

The last command showed me what packages are not updated. In my case I removed the packages (it was trash after experiments), then I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` again. There was no problem, update started.

Comment: You can also try `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your current version with the latest patches / updates. Run:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`

Then force the upgrade to 20.04 by running:

- `sudo update-manager -d`

Until first point release of 20.04 ... 20.04.1 ... upgrade will not be presented automatically. Until then the `-d` option is needed.

As @heynnema writes below `-d` means "development version". Right now there are no development version for next ubuntu (20.10). Since upgrading from 18.04 or 19,10 to 20.10, you should get a warning about that. If this  happens, let go of `-d` and try without it.

Comment: Doesn't -d get the development version?

Comment: @heynnema, at least for now there are no 20.10 development version, so -d do no harm.

Comment: The OP states that he went through the standard steps. The issue is most likely the presence of third-party package repositories. Simply unchecking their boxes in the update-manager (and then letting it update its caches) will probably be enough. I just did this myself.

Answer (score 1):

As posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Just remove all the content of /var/lib/apt/lists directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then follow [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Reboot the Ubuntu Linux system by tying the following command:

```
sudo reboot
```

Install the Ubuntu update tool, run:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

Start the upgrade procedure, run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Reboot the box, run:

```
sudo reboot
```

and I found this helpful, from [here](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/graphicsmagick?type=uninstall) or [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/cant-update-system-with-sudo-apt-update-on-ubuntu/19034), to remove those pesky 'ERROR' messages during updates

```
sudo apt-get remove graphicsmagick
```

where *graphicsmagick* is the package/software no longer supported etc

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a Digital Ocean droplet recently, but apt update and apt *upgrade returned 404s when attempting to download things. Running `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then re-running `sudo do-release-upgrade` again got me going.

Leaving this here for anyone else that gets stuck.

Comment: only solution that worked

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu Software Update and check any pending updates. Update them and you're done. Some updates do not execute using `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` first.

Comment: This makes no difference..

Answer (score -1):

First upgrade the packages:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

You will see a message similar to this:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded
```

Install the kept back packages manually.

```
sudo apt install package_name(s)
```

In my case it was:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```

After this run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again to ensure that everything is working fine.

Comment: If you wonder why you got a negative points - 1) you did not answer the original problem 2) you have an uncomplete command 3) you have a typo in the commandline 4) you advice to install a database tools, which hardly helps with upgrade to new LTS version.  But dont be dissapointed, read better the question and pay more attention next time.