# Upgrade from 19.10 to latest LTS: dist-upgrade doesn't solve "package held back" problem

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I want to update my VSP with Ubuntu 19.10 to the latest LTS release.

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-18-10-please-install-all-av) question, I've tried this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But I still get:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore. For upgrade information, please visit: http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

In particular, `sudo apt upgrade` gives this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  accountsservice apt apt-utils bind9-host dnsutils libldap-2.4-2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

I think I've broken something, since many comands are no longer working (for example: `virtualenv`, `python`, or `certbot`).

I've already tried rebooting the VPS.

How can I upgrade to the latest LTS release?

Here's my `sources.list`.

```
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan main restricted

# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu focal main restricted # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu focal universe # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan universe
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates universe # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu focal multiverse # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan multiverse
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

Comment: I also have a `sources.list.distUpgrade` file, which looks the same with a lot less commented lines: should I post that as well?

Comment: FYI: The supported upgrade window for 19.10 was from April to July.  Standard releases are released every 6 months so you have to be prompt with regular upgrades if you choose Standard releases. Compare this with LTS versions which are supported for at least 3 years and for 5 years in case of the default flavor that uses GNOME3.  That's not to say you can't still upgrade to 20.04, but if you are experiencing problems you might find it more expedient to just cleanly install 20.04