# Upgrade button to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS does nothing

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, update-manager

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and the Software Updater suggests me to upgrade my Ubuntu to 22.04.1 LTS. I click the  <kbd>Upgrade...</kbd>  button and nothing happens. What might be the problem in your opinion?

[image: Software Updater. The software on this computer is up to date. However, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS is now available(you have 20.04). Settings... Upgrade... OK]

Comment: Run `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal and you'll see what is going on.

Comment: It says "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." but I don't have any other thing to update in the "Software Updater".

Comment: I have one application update' code20 (20220729) but when I click it it says "Unable to update core20: snap has no updates available".

Comment: After restart I don't have any Ubuntu Software or application updates.

Comment: I'll try this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-18-10-please-install-all-av

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: update and upgrade told by that tidy package was keeping me back so I had to remove it. Then I was able to upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The first Ubuntu 22.04 point release has just been released, and many Ubuntu 20.04 users are trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 at the same time. There may be a temporary connectivity issue with your update server. Try waiting and clicking the  <kbd>Upgrade...</kbd>  button again in another 24 hours.

Comment: This answer might have made sense when you made it, but I encountered the same issue right now. Also, if there is a connectivity issue, why is there no error message? Presumably if things are working properly, it would test for the connection and if the connection timed out there would be an error message. Clearly something is not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same thing trying to upgrade to 23.10 from 23.04. Clicking on the Upgrade button would just close the dialog and nothing would happen. In the end, doing Pilot6's suggestion is the correct method.

First, using terminal, install update manager:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

Then, start the upgrade process:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This then showed the upgrade instead of just a blank screen. :)