# Broken drivers, broken res, can not upgrade to 22.10?

Tags: drivers, upgrade

Getting this error

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

tried this but does not work [Error while trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10: "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-18-10-please-install-all-av)

What next?

Some random update broke everything. Resolution is busted. Drivers are busted. Updates don't work. Upgrades don't work.

Someone has done something wonky. A friend also had to reinstall everything recently.

Likely will find another post answering all these questions.

What should I be doing next? I *think* i have disable most sources.

I can purge nvida and cuda etc and keep trying drivers but this seems expensive.

UPDATE:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed postfix shim-signed
```

I don't think I can remove these?

Comment: While 18.04 may have a few more days support, 18.10 is long EOL. The normal upgrade would be to 20.04. Check your repo names in /etc/apt/sources.list, at some point "archive" replaces the normal repo , then "old" replaces "archive".

Comment: I am on 22.04 it is busted. trying to get out of jail by upgrading to see if it wipes something.

Comment: @Nmath yes I still don't understand the issue ... it appears to be resolved but involved a lot of weird things to get through it. I think the error messages from various processes are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading solved ALL my problems.

What is very strange is the upgrade process took a very long time AND it asked me if I wanted to upgrade to Lunar Lobster 23.10 ... but now when I do lsb_release -a I see 22.10!?

Very strange.

Not only did my driver issues get fixed by gpu compat with various python libraries also started working again.

I still don't know what the issue was. Went through many cycles of purging and re-installing, updating etc before upgrading. And even to upgrade I couldn't until I manually uninstalled (i.e. sudo apt-get remove X) ALL the packages that were reported as held (they were *not* held) by the complaint from the upgrade process.

Hopefully this helps someone get out of dodge.